# When the console isn't open in chrome, some items are not longer clickable (some js calls stop working)

Tags: javascript, console

I have a section on my webpage in this form. The idea is that the div.content is originally hidden, and display only when the respective h3 is clicked. This works fine in firefox and safari. It also works fine in chrome, but ONLY when the console is open. When the console is closed, some of the headers are no longer clickable (I have the cursor set to pointer in the css file, and the cursor does not even show up as a pointer in this case.)

```
 <h3> Header 1 </h3>
 <div class="content"> 
     <p> Some content </p>
 </div>
 <h3> Header 2 </h3>
 <div class="content"> 
     <p> Some content </p>
 </div>
```

What could be causing this weird behavior? I thought originally that maybe my console.log calls were to blame, but each one of them is wrapped up (see below), so this shouldn't be the problem.

```
if (console) console.log("logging information");
```

Comment: Do you have a link? I imagine this might be caused by where you load your JS.

Comment: Here is a link: http://tinyurl.com/weirdjserror 

It happens on the second page (after clicking continue). The section "experiment length" should be clickable (like the other sections), but it isn't. If you open the console, it immediately becomes clickable.

What do you mean by where I load my js? Thanks!

Comment: Weird, I'm using 40 as well (Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit)) and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Okay, I was able to reproduce the bug. What I meant by "where you load your JS" is that if you load it in the head and it performs operations to the DOM, you have to make sure it only runs when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Btw you should think about reducing the preloading time - it's outrageously slow and you'll probably lose quite a number of visitors for that reason alone.

Comment: For performance reasons I would tell  you to put all JS files right before the end of the body tag.

Comment: I second @Donte'Trumble suggestion because it may also solve your problem

Comment: @howderek I'd rather use an onload handler. Or jQuery and `ready`.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble I haven't heard of this before. Do you mean that instead of putting all the js files in the <head> portion, I should put them in <body> at the very end? If so, I just did that, and I think the problem still persists.

Comment: I think the issue actually has to do with how you are using jQuery selectors. Give me a sec.

Comment: It seems that you are using the debug variants of the jquery lib. Use the minified version instead ( that makes for a size reduction of about 2/3, 250kB -> 80 kB ).  Also  consider keeping a local copy of the jquery lib instead of fetching it from jquery.com. Finally, consider fetching all the samples asynchronously - your subjects won't need them rifht after loading the page.

Comment: @collapsar Thanks for the suggestions. I updated to the minified versions and made them local.

Comment: @Donte'Trumble Weird, it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Hopefully this is it!

Your continue button is being hidden by other elements z-indexes. So what you do is on span#contText add z-index: 1000; and that should work... Hopefully. added cursor pointer for user feedback.

```
span#contText{
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Ah! This is beautiful! I can't believe it was something so simple. Thank you so much for your help. I was literally going crazy this morning trying to figure this out!

Comment: Your Welcome... It was driving me crazy as well. Thanks for the stress lol @pomegranate. Have a good day.

Comment: For future reference on my end, how did you manage to find out that this was the problem? :)

Comment: Haha, you too! And sorry for causing you so much stress.

Comment: I noticed the parent element #continue had a cursor pointer on it and it wasn't showing. So added z-index to #continue and nothing. So I thought you must have the selector for the click event going to the actual button. Then added z-index on the span#contText.